# Background image not appearing when inside header tag

Tags: html, css

I have the below code but somehow background image is not being picked up unless i add some tag inside the header in html. Any idea?

```
My HTML
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My tribute page to Steve Jobs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>

        </header>


        <div class="header-container">
            <p>The people who are crazy enough to think they can change the world are the ones who do.</p>
            <p>TIMELINE</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

My CSS

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1100px;
    background-color: white;
}

header {
    background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/steve_jobs-wide.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Try adding background size cover to the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background-image actually sets I guess. But your header does not have any size to append the background-image to. So basically you are putting an image on a 0x0px container. Set a size for the header and it should work as you intend.

```
    header { 
        background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/steve_jobs-wide.jpg");
        width: 100%;
        height:30px; //just an example height
        }
```

Comment: thanks worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need first to add width and height and background properties as you wish.

```
 header {
   background-image:url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/steve_jobs-wide.jpg");
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: thanks worked like a charm